# GCP Bigquery, I want to aggregate some values by a catogrical value in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have these data that I want to analyze, schema as follows

```
timestamp           price volume Qualifiers TradeCatogary
------------------- ----- ------ ---------- -------------
2016-07-11 01:00:00     3   2323          U           OML
2016-07-11 01:02:03   2.5    434          K           KCL
2016-07-11 01:03:34     4   3244          U           KCL
2016-07-11 01:23:00   2.3     45          K           OML
...
```

What I want is to calculate the total share, value of trade, trade count, and average price(VWAP = dollarTraded / totalVolume) of each 5min. Desired schema as follows

```
timestamp tradeCount totalVolume dollarTraded VWAP
--------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ----
```

This isn't hard and I managed it with SQL like this

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST((ROUND(UNIX_SECONDS(Date_Time) / 300) * 300) AS int64)) AS interval_alias1,
    count(*) AS cnt,
    SUM(Volume) AS ShareVolumeTraded,
    SUM(Price * Volume) AS DollarVolumeTraded,
    (SUM(Price * Volume) / SUM(Volume)) AS VWAP
FROM
    `dbd-sdlc-prod.HKG_NORMALISED.HKG_NORMALISED`
WHERE
    RIC = '1606.HK'
    AND Type="Trade"
    AND (Date_Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-07-11 00:00:00.000000') AND
    TIMESTAMP('2016-07-11 23:59:59.999999'))
    AND Volume >0
    AND Price >0
GROUP BY 
    ROUND(UNIX_SECONDS(Date_Time) / 300), interval_alias1
ORDER BY interval_alias1
```

However, I want to push my analyze a bit further, I want not just a total summary of trades, I'd like to have more specific analyze based on different combination of qualifiers and tradeCatogary, such as:

```
count_U volume_U dollar_U VWAP_U count_U_OML volume_U_OML dollar_U_OML VWAP_U_OML ....

there are two qualifiers and two catogaries in the example so there will be:
3(basic) + 2 * 3(only qualifier) + 3 * 2 * 2(qualifier and catogary combination) = 21 columns
If there are no such trade in these time slot, the value will be left 0 as default
```

I wish to manage these queries with one SQL execution, I'm not sure how to address it, please give me a hint or some, thanks in advance

Comment: Use ````GROUP BY ROLLUP````. Link -> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause

Comment: I'm a new learner to GCP BIgquery and even a new bee for SQL, so what I am going to ask is a bit fundamental. I have checked the "GROUP BY ROLLUP" clause and I noticed that the outcome is putting them row by row, I would like to arrange them as columns, is it possible? What's more, the "GROUP BY" clause only supports ROLLUP when there is no other element, however, the grouping by time should not be removed

Comment: Once you have it in rows. u can then use PIVOT to make them as cols. Link --> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator

Comment: That did help a lot, thank you so much, I guess I need to figure out how to firstly group the data by 5 min each and then use the rollup

Comment: Sorry I still have one question, after rollup group the qualifier and category, there are actually two columns, and just as what I have written up there, I'd wish to have only one column variable

Comment: Concat the two cols to generate one col value. Use CONCAT

Comment: Hi @AlfredLU, Did the suggestions in the comments help you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, [Group By Rollup](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause) is appropriate for your case. Group By Rollup returns the results of Group By on all  possible combinations of mentioned columns. Since you also want the output as columns rather than rows, you can use [pivot tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) to change rows to columns. Also for your other requirement i.e. to concatenate the outputs of two columns and make it as a single column, [CONCAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat) function can be used.